# Error while installing Noinstall version of mysql-5.6.23-winx64

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have downloaded the Noinstall version of mysql-5.6.23-winx64

As mentioned in [Starting MySQL Server on Microsoft Windows for the First Time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-server-first-start.html)

so I tried as following and get these bunch of error:

and sure using admin mode

c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
 5.6\bin\mysqld" --console

```
2015-04-03 20:56:02 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Amr.lower-test
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Amr.lower-test
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool p
ages
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlo
cked functions
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write
 mode
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGIN
E failed.
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Binlog end
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD
'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET
'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-04-03 20:56:02 6800 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysq
ld: Shutdown complete
```

and sure the following won't work

c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql.exe

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
 5.6\bin\mysqld" --install

```
Install/Remove of the Service Denied!
```

Comment: In what sense is MySQL Workbench involved here? All this problem is about is a bad installation of the MySQL server.

Comment: Whoops! Now it is updated, sorry my fault. Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A missing directory seems to be an issue.Create the directory C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\ with sufficient rights and see if it then starts ok.

Comment: Directory was already created. but I tried to create Amr.lower-test file and tried again and it worked correctly and tested. Thanks Norbert

Comment: @AmrHamza : You created the file yourself? Then this might still be a rights issue on the given directory. MySQL should have rights to create files and subdirectories in the data directory. You might run into this file creation issue again until that is really 100% correct.